# How to upload new multiple nodes with multiple auto-id

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im trying to update multiple nodes with multiple auto-id by using for-loop. However it always fail. i cant see anything updated on databse.
Is there any other way to implement it?

```
let ref = Database.database().reference().child("kardexes").child(newKardex.id)
ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in                        
   if (snapshot.exists()){
       for treatment in self.treatments {
            self.treatmentId = ref.child("treatments").childByAutoId().key

            var treatmentData = FirebaseDataType()

            treatmentData["name"] = treatment.name

            ref.child("treatments").child(self.treatmentId!).setValue(treatmentData){ (error, ref) in
              if let error = error {
                  Log.debug(" >>> error \(error.localizedDescription)")
                                    }
                                }                                

                            }
                        } else{
                                print("snapshot doesnt exist")
                            }
                        })
```

I expect to get the following result, but nothing get updated

```
kardexes
   |
-LkcSD2KJLwbCj8KAdsd
   |-treatments
        |-"-Lkc5MFEGsfbCj8KAmbo"
            |-name:"abc"            
        |-"-Lk5sKCKJLwbCj8KAofj"
            |-name:"def"
        |-"-Lk5sKFOELwbCj8KAjgu"
            |-name:"ijk"
```

Comment: Your question says you are trying to *update multiple nodes* but this `.childByAutoId().key` provides a key for a new node, not update an existing one. Maybe providing a bit more info about what you're trying to do would help as it's pretty unclear. Can you clarify your question?

Comment: @Jay , it's my bad. It should be like upload new nodes. At begnning, on the database, there is only kardexes with it's one autoId "-LkcSD2KJLwbCj8KAdsd". Under this environment, i need to create a node "treatments" and upload an array of data. Each data include it's own id(treatment id) and "name". Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is a bit unclear but I think you're asking how to create the 'kardexes' node so it looks like the structure presented in you question.

If so, here's the code that does that

```
func createKardexesNode() {
    let treatmentArray = ["abc", "def", "ghi"]
    let ref = self.ref.child("kardexes").child("-LkcSD2KJLwbCj8KAdsd").child("treatments")
    for treatment in treatmentArray {
        let childRefToAdd = ref.childByAutoId()
        childRefToAdd.child("name").setValue(treatment)
    }
}
```

running this code generates a node in Firebase that looks like this

```
{
  "kardexes" : {
    "-LkcSD2KJLwbCj8KAdsd" : {
      "treatments" : {
        "-Ll2dsJivnsH9QRM6MfV" : {
          "name" : "abc"
        },
        "-Ll2dsJivnsH9QRM6MfW" : {
          "name" : "def"
        },
        "-Ll2dsJivnsH9QRM6MfX" : {
          "name" : "ghi"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

note that self.ref is a class var that points to the root ref of *my* Firebase. Substitute your own.

Comment: Thanks for your help. After my investigation, i think my main issue is not in the code. I will post another question with more description for it.